# Prevent branches from being deleted on PR completion

Tags: git, azure-devops, pull-request

In Azure Devops I have a git repository with a develop branch.  We create multiple feature branches from this branch and merge code into develop via pull requests.  Once we complete the pull requests the feature branches get deleted.

I want to prevent this from happening.  I'd like to keep these feature branches.  How can I do that?

Comment: *Don't* check ["Delete <branch name> after merging"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/pull-requests?view=azure-devops#complete-the-pull-request)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe is there a way to make sure that this is not even an option?  In other words we cannot merge and delete branches at all.

Comment: **Why** do you want to retain feature branches? That's fairly uncommon. If you want to retain the commit history, then just don't squash merge.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Prevent branches from being deleted on PR completion

Indeed, unchecking the option **Delete  after merging** is the most straightforward solution.

However, we sometimes ignore checking this option in frequent PR. At this time, this option is not enough for us.

To resolve this issue, the workaround is **set branch security for the target branch**(multiple feature branches for your situation):

In Azure Devops `Branches` Tab -> click `…` button for `Feature` branch -> `Branch security` -> change `Force push (rewrite history, delete branches and tags)` as `Deny` for the users and groups -> Save changes.

[image]

Then, the option Delete  after merging will be unavailable:

[image]

**Note:**

- Delete source branch after merging option in PR completing window is not checked/selected by default, but based on the last time's setting. Such as if you deselect the option now, when you open the PR completing window next time, the Delete source branch after merging option will be deselected.
- Just like Daniel said, retain feature branches is not a normal operation, we have to know some of the problems it may bring. Like, if we select the Merge type is `squash commit` and retain feature branches at the first PR, we will get conflict when we second PR. Because we retain the commits on the feature branch.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Leo.  Are you saying that I will need to change the settings for each feature branch I create, each time?

Comment: @SachinKainth, Yes, Unfortunately, there is no template to set branch security for all feature branches, so , we have to change the settings for each feature branch you create. **But**, we do not need change this setting each time, because the feature branches are not deleted. We just need set it for all feature branches once.

Comment: @SachinKainth, So, how are things going? Please let me know if there is any progress.

Comment: If you are the one who created the branch, then the option won't be grayed out for you. I wish it was as sometimes it's checked and sometimes not. In a hurry sometimes we just merge without doing all the check/unchecking. It would be nice to set default checking behavior, and gray out unwanted behavior for all.