# disabling "delete branch" checkbox on pull requests in bitbucket

Tags: bitbucket, devops, branch

i was wondering if someone knows how to disable this checkbox from being clicked by users bc i don't want the feature branches to be deleted after merge in pull requests.
[image: checkbox]

i've managed to disable it by implementing branch restrictions, but the restriction is too general (disable the deletion of feature branches), and i don't want to disable the deletion of feature branches at all, i just want to restrict that checkbox so users don't delete it after a pull request.

i would need a similar solution to this one but in bitbucket.
[Prevent branches from being deleted on PR completion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56566170/prevent-branches-from-being-deleted-on-pr-completion/74305382#74305382)

Comment: No, there's not a direct aproach to this but i managed to do a workaround.
What i did was to implement branch restrictions
you have to do this to each branch, and if you have some external system creating branches (Feature-002) you could use an "*" to include all of them, like "feature*"

Responding to the question, branch restrictions allow to select one or more users and give only to them the acces to merge via pull requests, so other users can create PR with write acces, and even check that checkbox, but they wouldnt be able to merge the PR to the branch, so the branch wont be deleted